# Custom titlebar without the shadow

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I want to have a GUI kindof like how Market is.  Mainly I want a title with an icon and the name.  So I've disabled the default titlebar and are using a 9 patch image as my custom titlebar.  It looks great, but the top system bar ( cannot remember what's it called atm ) is casting a shadow on my application - specifically on my titlebar.  I've looked at the Market's custom titlebar and it doesn't have a shadow, or the shadow is below the three main buttons casting on the contentlist.

How can I remove the shadow from my custom titlebar, and maybe have it below - casting on the content?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you provide screenshots explaining?

Comment: I believe it's likely to be theme related. Have you tried using a light theme, for instance?

Comment: Open up Market. Do you see the shadow under the three buttons "Apps", "Games" and "Downloads"? The shadow is casted on the list, you see it when you scroll - I have that shadow casted over my custom titlebar in my application.

Comment: I can see what you mean Espen. I have a custom titlebar on my app and I have the following attribute in the activity element in the manifest file: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" and I've just noticed the slight shading at the top of my title bar (after reading your question!). I'm not sure if this is just an emulator issue - have you tried your app on your device?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984414/remove-notification-bar-shadow-in-android-app

Comment: @John J Smith: I have tried it on a device - HTC Desire. Same issue. Anyway, I'm close to figuring this out. It's sort of a hack, doing a combination of getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_title); and having to set the hight of the title bar in the theme. I found some links, and this is the closest: http://www.anddev.org/my_own_titlebar_backbutton_like_on_the_iphone-t4591.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this is that the title bar is a part of the theme and that one have to make changes to the current theme and set a custom layout for the title bar.  More info here: http://www.anddev.org/my_own_titlebar_backbutton_like_on_the_iphone-t4591.html